# Which ATMs in Germany have the lowest fees for the foreign Visa debit cards?

Tags: germany, fees-and-charges, atms, payment-cards

What ATMs in Germany are safe to use when it comest to the fee paid for using the foreign (other EU-country) Visa card? 
'
I have learned that the fees may very strongly and there are many "commercial" ATMs whose owners are going to earn as much money on fees as they can. So, what ATMs should I use when being in Germany? Are those from **Sparkasse** good? AFAIK this is the most popular bank in Germany.

Comment: Note that "provision" is a false friend - the correct english word is fee or comission. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Just a side note: Sparkasse is not a bank, it's a type of institution. I don't know all the details but there are hundreds of them in Germany (they do share a logo and work together but they remain separate institutions, often owned by municipalities). I am not sure how much of a difference it makes for ATM transactions but I think they have different online banking systems, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- When you have a card from another EU-country, it's possible that your bank has a partnership with one or more German banks and those will have the lowest fees. You should ask your bank.
- At the airports and train stations there are some ATMs that have very high fee-  avoid those. Use only ATMs that belong to banks (Postbank, Deutsche Bank, Sparkasse, Citi Bank etc..). I think that Sparkasse and Volksbank don't have low fees, but I'm not 100% sure.
- Before every withdrawal, the ATM will show you the fee and you can confirm or cancel.

Comment: At one ATM in Spain, I was asked whether to allow a rather small fee and I said OK.  I then got the money and a receipt that should the withdrawal, the small fee AND a very hefty "commission."  I have a bank that refunds to me all ATM fees (but not the commission).  If there are banks like that that you can use, you might consider switching.

Answer (score 4):

I have paid money off in **PostBank** ATM. The fee was relatively low, it does not show up in my bank account, and the exchange rates are varying, but it wasn't high for sure.

I have learned that **Sparkasse** is to be avoid at all cost because they have fees up to even 5%!

The ATM has not show any information about the fees!